# Ballot problem of probability- probability of the last vote

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

This is a math of the Introduction to Probability Models (11th edition) written by Sheldon M Ross. Here conditioning has been used on the last vote.

Pn,m = P{A always ahead|A receives last vote} * P{A receives last vote} + P{A always ahead|B receives last vote} * P{B receives last vote}

But how can

P{A receives last vote}

be equal to n/(n+m) ? The last vote can go to only one of all the candidates, so it should be

1/number_of_candidates

(Though the number of candidates is not mentioned here)

The same applies for B as well.

Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last vote cast must go to either $A$ or $B$. The question only cares about the two relevant candidates, so we can assume that there are a total of $m+n$ votes cast, $n$ of which went to $A$ and $m$ of which went to $B$. Thus, if we only look at the last vote, since each ordering is equally likely, the probability that it is one of these $n$ that went to $A$ is $\frac{n}{n+m}$.